# How to using python regex to extract contact page link only

Tags: python, scrapy

I am testing a python list

```
urls=[

 'https://www.example.com/about-us/',
 'https://www.example.com/our-projects/',
 'https://www.example.com/3c-metal-group/',
 'https://www.example.com/installation/',
 'https://www.example.com/inspection/',
 'https://www.example.com/contact-us/',
]
```

I need to match the about us link and contact us link only from this link of link with python regex

Comment: Can you please show your approach you came up with so far?

Comment: import re

urls=[

 'https://www.3cmetal.com/about-us/',
 'https://www.3cmetal.com/our-projects/',
 'https://www.3cmetal.com/3c-metal-group/',
 'https://www.3cmetal.com/installation/',
 'https://www.3cmetal.com/inspection/',
 'https://www.3cmetal.com/contact-us/',
]


re.findall('contact',urls)

i need the data to be https://www.3cmetal.com/contact-us/

Comment: i am developing a spider and it's need to going each website contact us and about us page and collecting email data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need regex? You can just check it substring in string:

```
>>> urls = [ '3cmetal.com/about-us', '3cmetal.com/our-projects', '3cmetal.com/3c-metal-group', '3cmetal.com/installation', '3cmetal.com/inspection', '3cmetal.com/contact-us', ]
>>> [i for i in urls if 'contact' in i]
['3cmetal.com/contact-us']
>>> [i for i in urls if 'contact' in i or 'about' in i]
['3cmetal.com/about-us', '3cmetal.com/contact-us']
```

Comment: i need the about us page link also

Comment: I've updated answer.

Comment: thanks it's working